# Nodejs memory usage

Tags: node.js, memory

I think I have a problem with memory usage. I have a node.js server :

```
var arcadeGames = require('./server/js/arcade');
var cardsGames = require('./server/js/cards');
```

requires modules that exports object required from  `.json` data

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
//var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
//var fs = require('fs');

app.get('/specificCategory/:id',function(req,res,next){ 
switch(req.params.id){

    case "Cards":
        console.log(cardsGames.titles);
        break;
    case "Action":
    console.log(actionGames.titles);
    break;
    default:
    console.log("undefined");
}


//var specificCaategory = require('./server/js/'+ req.params.id.toLowerCase());
    //var categoryTitlesAndUrlThumbs = spe
    //console.log(specificCaategory.titles);
})
```

(both way are working the same commented one or the one with switch)

the get function is called from browser by clicking the categories ex :Cards, Action and send the request through http, controller from angularjs. The problem is that when I `console.log`ed out on server first click on each category works fine, but after that, the server takes a lot of time to `console.log` out the info.(what will happends in browser if this is so hard for server).

Have I done something to load the memory so much?

Comment: Try to add `res.end();` after your switch case.

Comment: Phuu i got it now. i didn't send anything to with res.send() so he didn't call the res.end(); . I just read that if you call send() it will automatically call res.end(). Thanks Lazarev and thanks for correction tooo

Comment: Ok, glad to help you. I'll post it as the answer if you don't mind.

Comment: it is oke. I am not used to stackoverflow but i will catch up :D

Answer (score 1):

Add `res.end();` after your switch case.